# How to use callback event using functional React component

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I am trying to pass the next or prev week dates range from child to parent component. I am using functional component with hooks.
Any help or suggestion that might be useful to me for passing the correct date range from my [React calander](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-big-calendar)calendar.

Thanks in advance.

**Sample Code**
From `Calander component`, I want to select the date and want to pass it into `TestRequest` component.
For example, `toobar.label` returns `September 19 – 25` this needs to be changed with `startDate` as `2021-09-19` and `endDate` as `2021-09-25` accordingly.

```
//child component

export interface CalendarProps {
    events: any[],
    handleSelect: any,
    onClick: any,
    handleChange: any
}

const DatesComponent  = (toolbar: any) => {
    const back = () => { toolbar.onNavigate('prev'); };
    const next = () => { toolbar.onNavigate('next'); };
    return (
        <div className='calander-container'>
        <div className='calander-container-details'>
            <ChevronLeft  size='medium' onClick={back} className='arrow'/>
            <ChevronRight size='medium' onClick={next} className='arrow'/>
        </div>
        </div >
    )
};

const DatesComponent: React.FC<CalendarProps> = (props) => {
    return <>
        <Calendar
        selectable={true}
        popup={true}
        views={['week']}
        events={props.events}
        defaultView={Views.WEEK}
        scrollToTime={new Date(1970, 1, 1, 6)}
        defaultDate={new Date()}
        onSelectEvent={(event :any) => props.handleSelect(event)}
        onNavigate={(e :any) => props.onClick(e)}
        min={new Date(0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0)}
        max={new Date(0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0)}
        components={{
            toolbar: DatesComponent
        }}
        />
    </>
}
    
    export default DatesComponent;

//parent

cons TestRequest= () => {
    const [, setDate] = useState(null)
    const [details, setDetails] = useState(null)
    return <>
        <div className='calender-d'>
            <DisplayCalander setDate={setDate}
                setDetails={setDetails} getDetails={{details}}/>
        </div>
    </>
}
// @ts-ignore
export default withRouter(PendingRequest);


const DisplayCalander: React.SFC<DisplayAllCalendarProps> = ({ setDate, setDetails }) => {
    return (<>
    <DatesComponent 
        onClick={(e:any)=>{ setDate(e)}}
        handleSelect={(e:any) => setDetails(e)}/>
    </>)
};
```

**Update**
Finally I figured it out the way to get the week range by using `onRangeChange` [event](http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#prop-onRangeChange) .

*Updated code*

```
const DatesComponent: React.FC<CalendarProps> = (props) => {
    return <>
        <Calendar
        selectable={true}
        popup={true}
        views={['week']}
        events={props.events}
        defaultView={Views.WEEK}
        scrollToTime={new Date(1970, 1, 1, 6)}
        defaultDate={new Date()}
        onSelectEvent={(event :any) => props.handleSelect(event)}
        onRangeChange={(e :any) => props.handleChange(e)}
        onNavigate={(e:any) => props.onClick(e)}
        min={new Date(0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0)}
        max={new Date(0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0)}
        components={{
            toolbar: DatesComponent
        }}
        />
    </>
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Is the issue the formatting of what is being returned, or fact that nothing is being returned?

Comment: Thanks you Samuel for your time. I have figured it out one way to fine the week dates range with `onRangeChange` event . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the parent your usestate is missing a date variable

Comment: Hi Anthony thank you for your time. I am unable to pass the  event dates to my parent component. Do you mind to share some snippet that might help me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).